# Excel formula help - return a value based on two conditions

Tags: excel

Forgive me as I'm a bit of a novice with Excel and have no idea if this is possible or not. Looking for a formula to return one of four values, based on two criteria. One is a Drop-down list with either "Sun-Sat" or "Thur-Wed" options, and the other is a date value. If the date entered falls on a Monday or Tuesday it should return one value, and if the date entered falls on a Wednesday/Thursday/Friday it should return another.

```
                                    A         B
                                 Sun-Sat    Thurs-Wed
1 Monday/Tuesday                28/06/2015  25/06/2015
2 Wednesday/Thursday/Friday     5/07/2015   2/07/2015
```

Drop down box is cell B6 and Date is cell A6
I hope that is enough detail, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have these on the "Match" sheet:

```
          A                          B         C
1                                 Sun-Sat    Thurs-Wed
2 Monday/Tuesday                28/06/2015  25/06/2015
3 Wednesday/Thursday/Friday     5/07/2015   2/07/2015
```

And say you keep the first criterion(`Match!$A`) in `A2` and the second (`Match!$1`) in `B2`.
The formula you'll need is:

> =INDEX(Match!$1:$1048576;MATCH($A2;Match!$A:$A;0);MATCH($B2;Match!$1:$1;0))

The `MATCH()` formulae provides the indices that the `INDEX()` formula uses to identify the output cell.
As pnuts have highlighted I missed that it was one date and one validation.

> =INDEX(Match!$1:$1048576;MATCH(IF(OR(WEEKDAY($A6)=2;WEEKDAY($A6)=3);"Monday/Tuesday";"Wednesday/Thursday/Friday");Match!$A:$A;0);MATCH($B6;Match!$1:$1;0))

is an augmented version for when the `A` column contains dates. Note: I treated the two sets as alternatives, the weekends will be wrongly classified if existent.

*Edit not from answerer - layout might be closer to OP's, with formula adjusted to suit (also shows results from various inputs):*

[image: SO31186697 example]

Comment: Thanks a lot. `=INDEX(Match!$1:$1048576;MATCH(IF(OR(WEEKDAY($A6)=2;WEEKDAY($A6)=3);"Monday/Tuesday";"Wednesday/Thursday/Friday");Match!$A:$A;0);MATCH($B6;Match!$1:$1;0))` is the way to go.

Comment: The original one was referring to the second row, yeah. The augmented one refers to row 6: dropdown cell `$B6` is used as a drop-down, while `$A6` is the date per se.

Comment: Yeah, try "Sun-Sat" in B6.